# Handling same type of exceptions in multiple ways

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one method that give same type of exception but I need to handle it in different ways
like:

```
try:
    # lets authenticate
except AuthenticationException:
       #handle it in way 1
except AuthenticationException:
      # handle it in way 2
except AuthenticationException:
      # handle it in way 3
except AuthenticationException:
      # handle it in way 4
```

We get same error `AuthenticationException` but it should not fail; it should try all 4 possible ways.

Is there any good way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to say a retry of same logic in 4 different ways ?

Comment: How should the program decide in which way to handle the exception? If it should just try all ways, why not put them into one exception handler?

Comment: yeah retry how can I do it for different different ways of hanlding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrancisCagney has already explained, you would expect each `except` to cater for unique conditions. The obvious solution would be to try to write the exception processing in such a way that it would handle the possible problems so that you only execute the relevant handler, rather than trying them sequentially. However, if you want it to try 4 different things, each of which might cause a new exception, one way of catering for this would be to wrap those 4 different ways in their own `try/except` statements:

```
try:
    # lets authenticate
except AuthenticationException:
    try:
       # handle it in way 1
    except:
        pass
    try:
       # handle it in way 2
    except:
        pass
    try:
       # handle it in way 3
    except:
        pass
    try:
       # handle it in way 4
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of multiple except clauses is to handle different exceptions differently.

```
try:
    <things that might fail>
except NameError as ex:
    <handle name error>

except AuthenticationException as ex:
    if ex.cause == 0:
        <handle cause 0>
    elif ex.cause == 'hello':
        <handle cause 1>
```

Now your AuthenticationException might have more information indicating why the exception was raised, but that's handled with if inside the single except clause for this exception.

Comment: cause is not 0, 1, 2 how it would

Comment: all ex.caused are same Authentication Failure